# SOQL from Apex class - Internal server error

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to get the AccountId of the Opportunity. I use `recordId` (opportunity ID) to pass to my Apex method.
But I am getting this weird error:

`Error: An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 223074523-231760 (-1434965262)`

A google search brings up nothing. What am I missing here?

```js
public with sharing class Foo {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Opportunity fetchAccountId(String opportunityId) {
        return [SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityId];
    }
}
```

```js
export default class MyFirstWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('accountId', await fetchAccountId(this.recordId))
```

Running the query in the console works fine.

I've also tried the `getRecord` function but it does not appear to support FKs.

Comment: And if you move it out of `connectedCallback` and avoid `await`, calling the method imperatively in the normal LWC way? The function is misleadingly named, BTW. It should be `getOpportunityById` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters need to be placed in an object, as in:

```
fetchAccountId({opportunityId:this.recordId});
```

Pay attention to the casing of the parameter, as JavaScript is Case-Sensitive.

The error message is itself meaningless without internal access to Salesforce logs, but in this case, it's actually pretty well known that you'll get a server error if you don't format the payload correctly.

Comment: Ah nice. Thanks for that catch and swift answer.

Comment: @dan-klasson You're welcome! It's so easy to make these kinds of mistakes, you'd think they'd at least put in proper error handling for this one.